# expressjs - Request body changes even when not used

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API developed in ExpressJs that looks like this:

```
router.post('/devices/data/*', function (req, res, next) {
  reqBody = req.body
  console.log(reqBody)
  var pmsCache = reqBody.pms; //pms key exists in body
  pmsCache.k1 = K1; //Adding a new key
  pmsCache.k2 = K2; //Adding a new key
  //
  // Insert into Redis pmsCache - successful
  //
  // Trying to insert into PostgreSQL
  rdbmsPool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack)
      throw err
    } else {
      var v;
      var u = true;
      var pms = reqBody.pms
      console.log(reqBody) // This has K1 and K2 - Why ?
      //
      // Logic to insert values into db
      //
      release()
    }
  }
  )
});
```

The `req.body` some how gets changed after I have done my Redis DB update. Why does the body change?

Comment: the problem is not clear, can you explain more? what happens when it gets changed?

Comment: The question is: _why_ does it change at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript manage the objects by referencing**

Means when you assign the `reqBody.pms` into `pmsCache` then it is not creating a new variable in memory it just assigning the address of the original variable.

Read more about javascript object referencing

https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

To solve your problem you should to use this

```
function deepClone(data){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
} 

var pmsCache = deepClone(reqBody.pms);
```

Comment: So, when an object is passed as an argument to a function, then it is not passed by reference? In the solution mentioned above, `data` is not a reference to `reqBody.pms`? What if, I had `var pmsCache = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: it will pass by reference but the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); ` will create clone of this and assign to variable. and you can also use directly this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you mean that `reqBody` changes, which is as expected, because you're not properly declaring that variable at the start of the function, which means it gets promoted to a global variable *and shared between all requests*.

The fix is to use proper variable declaration:

```
router.post('/devices/data/*', function (req, res, next) {
  const reqBody = req.body;
  ...
```

Comment: I believe this issue will occur after declaring the variable as well because javascript assign variable with reference.

Comment: @Aabid yeah, now that I'm taking a closer look at the code, that's indeed an additional problem with it.